# Testing con Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero testear el login de usuario solamente con PHPUnit por recomedaciones varias ya que Laravel Dusk se vuelve lento.

Mi problema es que quiero testear la parte de cuando el usuario ingresa datos en el formulario y no se si se puede realizar eso

```
   $this->actingAs($user); //USUARIO CREADO ANTERIORMENTE

   //When
   $response = $this->get(route('home'));

   //Then
   $response->assertStatus(200)
   ->assertViewIs('home');
```

La comprobación que puedo hacer es que un usuario logueado puede ir a la ruta home, pero no cuando rellena los formularios.

Comment: ¿cuál es el error o problema puntual?

Comment: testear que tengo un formulario con el input email y el input password y que al completar esos inputs se loguea bien. Porque yo puedo testear que al loguearme me lleva a la ruta correcta, pero si el input en vez de decir email, dice emal por error, el login no va andar. Entonces quiero probar el circuito completo. Desde el formulario, hasta la ruta home @Shaz

Answer (score 1):

Pues creo que lo que buscas es la funcion `type` que simula el ingreso de datos en los campos `input` de html.

**Por ejemplo:**
Se tiene el siguiente codigo html, donde existen los `input`s de **email** y **password** y el boton **Login**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('login') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ej:email','required']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contrase&ntildea</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese su contrase&ntilde;a',"required"]) !!}
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Puedes hacer una funcion de prueba de la siguiente forma.

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $this->visit('/login');//pagina de login
    $this->type('unEmail@gmail.com', 'email');//email es el name del input.
    $this->type('contraseña', 'password');//password es el name del input.
    $this->press('Login');//Login es el contenido del button.
    $this->seePageIs('/home');// pagina de redireccion.
}
```

ejecutas `phpunit` en tu consola, dentro de tu proyecto y listo.

Para que dicha funcion se ejecute de forma correcta la contraseña y el email deben de pertenecer a un usuario en la base de datos, ademas de que la funcionalidad del login debe de estar completa.

Comment: Pero esto seria usanado dusk? mi idea es solo usando phpunit, porque me dijeron que dusk es muy lento. O puedo usar dusk para casos particulares como este?

Comment: Pues entonces estoy mal, siempre lo use pensado que es phpunit.

Comment: tal vez la siguiente pagina te aclare algo https://styde.net/como-funcionan-las-pruebas-de-integracion-en-laravel-5-1/